# Remove specific characters in string using a given list in python

Tags: python

```
punctuation_chars = ["'", '"', ",", ".", "!", ":", ";", '#', '@']
def strip_punctuation(x):
    for i in punctuation_chars:
        for i in x:
            if x=="i":
                x.replace("i","")
                return x
m= "Twi@sd"
t=strip_punctuation(m)
print(t)
```

I am trying to remove specific characters in the string using above code . What is the issue here ?

Comment: `replace` method not an in place operation because strings are immutable in python.

Comment: You're masking `i`.

Comment: What's your expected output? `x == "i"` checks for string `"i"` not the variable `i`. And you're masking previous loop's `i` variable with the next loop `for i in x`

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable. Hence you would want to assign it back.
`i` is a variable. By using `"i"` it is treated as a string.
try

```
punctuation_chars = ["'", '"', ",", ".", "!", ":", ";", '#', '@']
def strip_punctuation(x):
    for i in punctuation_chars:
        if i in x:
           x= x.replace(i,"")
    return x

m= "Twi@sd"
t=strip_punctuation(m)
print(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give your variables more meaningful names, get rid of `if ... in mystring` and you'll see the issue:

```
punctuation_chars = ["'", '"', ",", ".", "!", ":", ";", '#', '@']


def strip_punctuation(string):
    for char in punctuation_chars:
        string = string.replace(char, "")
    return string


m = "Twi@sd"
t = strip_punctuation(m)
print(t)
```

This yields

```
Twisd
```

---

Alternatively use a regular expression, in the end that's what they were made for:

```
import re

punctuation_chars = ["'", '"', ",", ".", "!", ":", ";", '#', '@']
m = "Twi@sd"
rx = re.compile(rf"""[{"".join(punctuation_chars)}]+""")
m = rx.sub("", m)
print(m)

# Twisd
```

Comment: You can avoid `if char in string:` as it will replace only if it is available.

Answer (score 0):

Replace method is not an in place method, you need to store the value into a variable to use it.

Inner loop is also not needed for this purpose.

Have a look at the solution, comment if you have any query.

Code:

```
punctuation_chars = ["'", '"', ",", ".", "!", ":", ";", '#', '@']
def strip_punctuation(x):
    for i in punctuation_chars:
        if i in x:
            x=x.replace(i, '')
    return x

m= "Twi@s:d"
t=strip_punctuation(m)
print(t)
```

Output:

```
Twisd
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through `punctuation_chars` and replace each character

```
def strip_punctuation(x):
    for c in punctuation_chars:      
        x = x.replace(c, "")
    return x
```

`str.replace()` returns a new string so you have to assign it to a new variable each time (python strings are immutable)

Answer (score -1):

Here were the issues:

1. Strings are immutable. You need to set the string equal to the string in the replacement function.
2. You checked whether the character was equivalent to the string `"i"` as opposed to the variable `i`.
3. You indented the return statement so that it would be called after the first replacement. If it was not replaced, it would return `None`.

This is the code:

```
punctuation_chars = ["'", '"', ",", ".", "!", ":", ";", '#', '@']


def strip_punctuation(x):
    for i in punctuation_chars:
        for j in x:
            if i == j:
                # print(i)
                x = x.replace(i, "")
    return x


m = "Twi@sd"
t = strip_punctuation(m)
print(t)
```

**Output:**
`Twisd`

Comment: Yeah, I did. It worked perfectly. Not sure why you gave me thumbs down. Why don't you copy+paste it and try running it yourself?

Comment: Now it's fixed.. I'm going to edit it and add explanation.

Comment: @Jan When did you run it? Before I edited it about 7 minutes ago? It returns Twisd for me.

Comment: @Jan You're right about the indentation errors. It wouldn't format when I edited and tried to paste it back in, so I had to space it out manually to format it. I am aware. Either way, the logic is valid, and I just fixed the indentations.